Gray code permutation notation
I 'm trying to understand the notation of the Gray code permutation but since I only know 2-row matrix notation for permutations, I would like an explanation for the notations below . I understand the  reflected-Gray code concept with its formula but this notation is not clear to me
https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Gray_code_permutation_powers

The n-bit Gray code $G_n$ is a permutation of the integers from 0 to
2n − 1, whose only fixed points are 0 and 1.
The powers of $G_n$ form the the cyclic group $Z_n$, if n is a power of
2. In general they form the the cyclic group $Z_m$, with  ${\displaystyle m=2^{\lfloor \log _{2}n\rfloor }}$ (which is
A062383(n−1)).
Each row has the exponent k on the left, then the vector abbreviating
the Walsh permutation, and on the right the permutation itself. It can
be seen, that each $m×2n$ matrix is the top left corner of the next one.
2-bit

    0         1   2         0   1   2   3
    1         1   3         0   1   3   2 
3-bit

     0         1   2   4         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
     1         1   3   6         0   1   3   2   6   7   5   4
     2         1   2   5         0   1   2   3   5   4   7   6
     3         1   3   7         0   1   3   2   7   6   4   5 
4 bit

0         1   2   4   8         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
1         1   3   6  12         0   1   3   2   6   7   5   4  12  13  15  14  10  11   9   8
2         1   2   5  10         0   1   2   3   5   4   7   6  10  11   8   9  15  14  13  12
3         1   3   7  15         0   1   3   2   7   6   4   5  15  14  12  13   8   9  11  10


